# How to bind to DOM Events on WebKitX with FoxPro

Tags: browser, vb6, activex, visual-foxpro

I'm trying to catch the document.click event of a ActiveX-Browsercontrol in Foxpro. It works with the default BrowserOLE and [this approach](https://west-wind.com/presentations/shellapi/shellapi.asp#Capturing%20Browser%20Events) (at the bottom).

However, we need to have more Html5 compatibility and I am using [WebKitX - ActiveX](https://github.com/mobileFX/WebKitX) now. Unfortunately the examples are for VB6 and I need to implement it in a FoxPro - Project. The browser itself is working, just the addEventListener - method is mystery to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the control you're using, but check out the EventHandler() function in Help.

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of the WebKitX (Jan 2018) you can set the events you want to receive using WebKitX.Events = ON_CLICK + etc.. and receive notifications from OnEvent generic event handler. So you don't need to use addEventListener any more.